# Merge multiple rows into 1 transactional data

Tags: google-bigquery, apriori

Need your help to advise me on this one :).

I want to create a transactional dataset.
This is my initial dataset

```
user_id    date_key    channel      order_id
123        1 sep       Affiliates   -
123        2 sep       Price Comp   -
123        3 sep       Direct       12342213
435        2 sep       Organic      -
435        7 sep       Direct       45485485
```

And I want modify above table into a transactional dataset like this.
It will show a user journey from its first visit into purchase (let say user_id 123 visit from Affiliates then Price Comp and Direct (ended up purchasing).

```
user_id    channel_journey                   order_id
123        Affiliates - Price Comp - Direct  12342213
435        Organic - Direct                  45485485
```

Do you guys know and advise how can I get into the second table?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `STRING_AGG`:

```
SELECT user_id, STRING_AGG(channel, ' - ' ORDER BY date_key), MAX(order_id)
FROM `dataset.table`
GROUP BY user_id
```